# Using Join on list id in a field

Tags: mysql, join

My problem is I have a weird database with some list of id a field and I want to make a join with an other table , maybe I have to use a Regex to join this two table but I don't know the pattern to use

Here is an exemple

Table A

```
     id   |   dos_id   |   status   
---------------------------------
     1    |   16 18    |     1
     2    |   30       |     1
     3    |   92 21    |     0
```

Table B

```
 dos_id    |   other_id   |   label   
---------------------------------
     16    |   32         |     toto
     18    |   666        |     titi
     21    |   99         |     tutu
     ....
     91    |   34443      |     zerezf
```

I want to join A to B on dos_id field
dos_id is a text Type in Table A

Comment: Please mention the data type of dos_id

Comment: it s a text Type

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FIND_IN_SET` here, after replacing space in the `dos_id` field with comma, in the first A table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON FIND_IN_SET(b.dos_id, REPLACE(a.dos_id, ' ' , ',')) > 0;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that the A table is effectively storing unnormalized `dos_id` information.  Ideally, each `dos_id` value should have its own record in both tables.  As such, you should not view this answer as a long term solution for what is likely a design problem.